# What does greater than shape mean in Unity Launcher?

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher

Sometimes I find out that application I'm using at the moment has `>` (greater than) letter on the left of its icon in Unity Launcher instead of standard triangle. But in [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/unity-launcher-shapes.html), there isn't this shape mentioned. What does presence of this shape mean?

Comment: That the Ubuntu Documentation does not mention it is worthy of a bug report, which I will enter.

Comment: Sure, just take a look at the discussion under accepted answer in order to provide additional information, please

Comment: I had not seen your last comment below. I'm saying just that the normal behavior not mentioned in the document is an issue also.[Link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-docs/+bug/1453158)

Comment: That is a separate issue and not a doc bug. I am dealing with the doc bug.

Comment: Oh, sure, sorry for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the corresponding application is running, but its window is not on the current workspace :)

on the current workspace:

[image]

on another workspace:

[image]

If you click on the icon, the workspace usually switches to the one with the application's window on it.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand that shape. But I don't use workspaces (as it is in default)! Is it a bug then?

Comment: Or I maybe by mistake sometimes press down the keyboard shortcut to move current app into the next workspace (even if I have them disabled) and then there shows up `>` (if any shortcut for that exists)

Comment: @aleskva You can find out if you have set workspaces somehow by two commands: `dconf read /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/vsize` and `dconf read /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/hsize` both should be 1, else you have workspaces enabled :)

Comment: Both output me 1

Comment: @aleskva *and* you have workspaces disabled in Appearances > Behaviour? That's a bug then, not the correct behaviour...

Comment: Yes, disabled! I'll fill in a bug on launchpad when it appears again.